# In Julia, how do I get the index of the first element in a sorted array that exceeds a certain value?

Tags: arrays, julia

Here is my code (`x` is the sorted array):

```
lookup_value = 310.0
x = [298.0, 303.0, 308.0, 313.0, 323.0]
if (issorted(x))
    idx = searchsorted(x, lookup_value)
end
```

In this particular case, the value of idx is:

```
4:3
```

Here, I'd like to extract either the "4" (the first element exceeding my look up value) or "3" (the last element that does not exceed the look up value).  However, I'm unable to do so by converting the range to an array, as all I get from the following command is an empty array:

```
julia> collect(idx)
0-element Array{Int64,1}
```

Note that the lookup value of 310.0 is only an example; this variable could take on different values.

Comment: If the array is sorted use `searchsortedfirst` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just realised its possible to use `idx.start` and `idx.stop` to access the start and end of a range.

```
julia> idx
4:3
julia> idx.start
4
julia> idx.stop
3
```

The first element that exceeds the lookup value is `x[idx.start]`.
The last element that does **not** exceed the lookup value is `x[idx.stop]`.

Comment: Alternatively, `first(idx)` and `last(idx)` also work. These have the slight benefit of being slightly more general, although that is not important here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to the accepted answer. I was going to add it as a comment, but apparently I'm not allowed to do that:

You should definitely *not* use `idx.start` and `idx.stop`. Type fieldnames in Julia are (normally) considered implementation details and not part of the interface. They can change without warning or deprecation.

You should use `first(idx)` and `last(idx)` as suggested by Fengyang Wang.